# Select INTO when all columns have the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How can I select the results ob this query INTO a new table.
Select INTO doesnt work since all the columns have the same name: N
Thank you.

```
WITH Balls(N)
 AS (SELECT number
     FROM  master..spt_values
     WHERE type='P'
     AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 41)
SELECT *
FROM   Balls B1
       JOIN Balls B2
         ON B2.N > B1.N
       JOIN Balls B3
         ON B3.N > B2.N
       JOIN Balls B4
         ON B4.N > B3.N
       JOIN Balls B5
         ON B5.N > B4.N
       JOIN Balls B6
         ON B6.N > B5.N
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign different names:

```
SELECT b1.number as number1,
       b2.number as number2,
       b3.number as number3,
       b4.number as number4,
       b5.number as number5,
       b6.number as number6
INTO my_table
FROM . . .
```